# How to perform Java lambda function decomposition

Tags: java, lambda

I have been learning how to do composition of lambda expressions using the `andThen` and `compose` functions, for example:

```
Function<SceneObject> transform = scaleX2.andThen(scaleY2).andThen(rotateZ45);
```

Is there a way to remove one of the steps in the resulting function?

So, in the above example `transform.decompose(scaleY2)` would result in `transform = scaleX2.andThen(rotateZ45)`.

Comment: Who said it's possible? What if `scaleY2` is `Integer::parseInt` and `rotateZ45` is `Math::abs`?

Comment: Luckily you can't do such a thing, as it would lead to horribly unmaintainable code. You'd just be pot-luck removing a piece of functionality from within the middle of another piece of functionality. It may make sense in your above example, as you know what the different parts are, but in general you wouldn't and couldn't know what functions another function may or may not be composed of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with that code. `Function.andThen` is implemented by constructing a lambda expression, which completely hides the details of the two functions used to construct it.

An alternative approach would be to use your own type, say `Transform<T, R>` which can wrap the equivalent function, and can then support a decompose operation.

```
import java.util.Optional;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Transform<T, R> {
    class AndThen<T, R, S> implements Transform<T, S> {
        final Transform<T, R> first;
        final Transform<R, S> second;

        AndThen(Transform<T, R> first, Transform<R, S> second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        @Override
        public S apply(T t) {
            return second.apply(first.apply(t));
        }

        @Override
        public <U> Optional<Transform<T, U>> decomposeFst() {
            return Optional.of((Transform<T, U>)first);
        }
        @Override
        public <U> Optional<Transform<U, S>> decomposeSnd() {
            return Optional.of((Transform<U, S>)second);
        }

    }

    default <S> Transform<T, S> andThen(Transform<R, S> next) {
        return new AndThen<T, R, S>(this, next);
    }

    R apply(T t);

    default <S> Optional<Transform<T, S>> decomposeFst() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    default <S> Optional<Transform<S, R>> decomposeSnd() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        final Transform<Double, String> f = Object::toString;
        final Transform<String, Integer> g = String::length;
        final Transform<Double, Integer> h = f.andThen(g);
        final int i = h.apply(1.234);

        final Optional<Transform<Double, String>> f2 = h.<String>decomposeFst();
        final Optional<Transform<String, Integer>> g2 = h.<String>decomposeSnd();

        final String s = f2.get().apply(1.234);
        final int j = g2.get().apply(s);

        System.out.println(s + " : " + j);
    }
}
```